# Interpret the impulse response when define shocks in terms of variances of the residual of the equation

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, structural-equation-modeling, macroeconomics, impulse-response

I’m trying to interpret the meaning of the shocks when they are written in terms of standard errors. I have constructed a multi-country Global Projections Model similar to IMF's model [here.](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2008/wp08279.pdf) Suppose the equations for the endogenous variables are:

Y_GAP = output gap in % terms = log(real GDP) - 100* log(potential GDP)

There is a separate equation that defines how output gap relates to its lagged values and other endogenous variables with a residual term. So it is

Y_GAP = linear combination of other variables + ERROR_Y

This is equation 13 of page 12 of the paper.

In Dynare when we compute the IRFs, we define the standard errors of the residual of the equation.

If I set the standard error on ERROR_Y to be 0.1, would that mean that we are imposing a shock of 10 percent i.e. the output gap rises by 10 percent? What if I want the output gap to fall by 10 percent, how would I reverse the direction of shock so that it’s reflected in the impulse response functions? I was thinking that since the standard errors measure the variability around the mean, we can’t obviously have negative standard errors to reflect the negative output gap.

Similarly, if there is another equation that defines:

inflation_rate = some_variables + ERROR_INF

This is eq 14.

Again, if I set the standard error on this error term to be 0.1 (i,e, se(ERROR_INF)), would that mean that we letting inflation rate to rise 10 percent ? What if I want the inflation rate to fall by 10 percent, how would I reverse the direction of shock?

Comment: That article appears to be 80 pages long, could you let us know what page those equations are from?

Comment: oh but yeah I think you're confounding "standard error" with "error term": while the standard error represents variation, and so is unsigned, an error term  may be positive or negative representing higher or lower Y_GAP than would be expected, respectively. Thus ERROR_Y, which refers not to the standard error, but to the error term, may be positive or negative. Sometimes people use the term "residual" instead of "error term" (though there is a difference).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've edited the post and mentioned the page and equation number. No, I am not confounding here. When we find the IRFs in dynare, we have to mention the standard error of the residual term. I tried to get help in the dynare forum, but to no avail. So, I thought I might ask here.

Comment: Thanks for updating! Oh, OK, I'm just not familiar with using the term "standard error" to describe the standard deviation of the residuals/error term. But anyways, yes, if I understand everything correctly, your interpretation is almost correct; I'm going to submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the linked article, the first equation is describing the output gap $y$, defined as the difference between actual logGDP $Y:=\log X$ and potential logGDP $\bar{Y}:=\log\bar{X}$, so $y = \log X - \log\bar X = \log\frac{X}{\bar X}$.

So if $y = \mu$ initially, we are left after the shock with:

$\mu+\epsilon=\log\frac{X}{\bar X}+\epsilon = \log\frac{X}{\bar X}+\log e^\epsilon$

$ = \log [\frac{X}{\bar X} e^\epsilon]$

So if $\epsilon=0.1$, if we're looking at things in terms of GDP ratios, the change is not 10 percent but $100\times e^{0.1}$ percent.

If we're looking at the output gap directly, which is defined in log-space, we can no longer talk about a percent increase/decrease, but rather just add/subtract.

(I'm assuming natural logarithms, but now that I think of it maybe the econometric community is using base 10, keep that in mind).

It's similar for Eq 14.

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for mathematically explaining it.